# Is there an add-in for VS2008 to manage favourite solutions/projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, favorites

The "Recent Projects" section on the startup page in VS2008 feels pretty useless to me.

I'm used to checking out multiple repositories to work on different features. Our repository structure is pretty deep. The File->"Recent Projects" menu does not show enough of the path for me to figure out which project it is going to open. The closest I can get is hovering over projects in the "Recent Projects" section on the startup page, because then I can read the whole path in the statusbar. Still I tend to opening projects frequently to test different ideas, but in general I only work on a few projects.

I think it would be great to have a "Favourite projects" section instead of a "Recent Projects" with entries I could name myself.

Does anyone know of such an add-in for VS2008?

Comment: I do not know of any for VS2008, but I was watching the episodes that they have on VS2010 and it will feature what you are looking for right in there. I know it doesn't answer your question at the moment, but it might be something you'll want to look at in the future and possibly a reason to switch to VS2010 early.

Comment: The feature is to "pin" projects to the recent list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) has a feature that's pretty close to what you describe.

The details of the **Favorite Solutions** feature can be found under the [Features to enhance your Visual Studio experience](http://www.mztools.com/v6/features.aspx#EnhanceExperience) heading.

> This feature is intended to replace
>   the Recent Projects or Start Page
>   features of Visual Studio, which have
>   some flaws: a recent project is not
>   always a favorite project...

Although this tool is *NOT* free, it does offer the feature you are looking for. You can try it out for [30 days](http://www.mztools.com/v6/download_demo.aspx).

Comment: It would have been nice if it was free, but one can't have everything.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make shortcuts to .sln file and put them in your desktop or Quick launch bar? then just one click and you can open your project and wait for VS2010 which will have the favorite projects feature.
Actually our repostitory structure is also very deep and I also want this feature but couldn't figure out. I changed the number of items recent project displays from 4 to 10 using tools -> options. This displays almost all my projects I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

[Favorites Menu for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/00F3B972-CB54-47F2-AC56-B2F48C77A74D) (For Files Only)

In case you are not able to find it online I can host it for you if you need it.

[Download Link.](http://depositfiles.com/files/6fm5h1q5p)

Alternatively you can use the MRU Cleaner addin to periodically clear the resent list

Comment: I guess "files" also include .sln and .csproj files, so this might be a good solution right?

Comment: I have it installed,you can only do files (*.cs) etc.

Comment: You *can* edit the .favitem file XML to point to .sln & .csproj files, but they open in plain text mode if you use the shortcut.

I'm using it to keep track of where particular version/branch .sln files (like release 4.5, SP6 branch) are located.  The stock 'Recent Projects' list is OK but it's too short for me & mouseover one every item to find a particular one is a pain.